# Can't pass array to view with asynchronous methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, meteor, helper

I'm building a Dapps connected with Ethereum Blockchain. I have a JavaScript function that call an asynchronous methods inside.

```
async function getFiles(id, array){
    if(id < 2){
        myContract.consultFile.call(id,"0x2b461Db580028F263351B969cFd8542db696787E",function(err, res){
            array.push({title : res[0], description : res[1]});
            getFiles(++id, array);
        });
    }
    return array;
}
```

Should this first methods be async?

Then I have in my helper a function that call the previous one. This is the closest version I've got but it's returning a promise object.
With this version I can see with `console.log()` that the [[PromiseValue]] is right.
But when I try to display it in my view with {{#each files}} with the underneath code, nothing happend, whereas if I return tmp I cans see [Object Promise].
It the array well send ? How should I display the array ?

```
Template.myDocuments.helpers({
    'files': function(){
        var tmp = getFiles(0,[]);
        tmp.then(function(val){
        console.log(val);
        return val;
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayFile(callback){
    callback(0,[]);
}

function getFiles(id, array){
    while(id++ < 2){
         myContract.consultFile.call(id,"0x2b461Db580028F263351B969cFd8542db696787E",function(err, res){
        array.push({title : res[0], description : res[1]});
    }
    console.log(array);

}
displayFile(getFiles);
```

The above code should allow the async function to run correctly by using callbacks, which enforce waiting for the the asynchronous call to finish successfully, upon which, everything below the callback will also run. Unfortunately, since the callback is asynchronous, you can't return a value from it to a synchronous function. But if the array is global it should have the value you want it to after displayFile(getFiles) is called.

[This](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) may be more helpful to understanding callbacks and asynchronous programming in javascript

Comment: This didn't work for me... I've managed to do it by putting the call directly into the onCreated() method and when pushing  into the array use TemplateVar.set each time.